# how to identify invalid date and replace default date

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How to identify inserted date is in correct format or not. sample_date column data type is in varchar.  Here i inserted two values '25-02-1999' and '2004'. When i found invalid date in sample_date column i want to replace with some dummy date.

```
Example: 

        create table sample(sample_date varchar2(10 char));
        insert into sample values('25-02-1988');
        insert into sample values('2004')
        insert into sample values('2005')
        insert into sample values('2006')
        I want to replace 2004,2005,2006 with dummy date('01-01-1988')
```

Comment: Why are you storing a date as a string? You could create a function to see if a string represents a date - and return a fixed value if it doesn't - and could even allow/convert various formats, but you'd need to decide what counts as 'valid'.

Answer (score 0):

Store your values as a `DATE` datatype, all your date related issues will become much simpler...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE sample(sample_date DATE);

INSERT INTO sample (sample_date) VALUES (TO_DATE('25-02-1988', 'DD-MM-YYYY'));

INSERT INTO sample (sample_date) VALUES (TO_DATE('2004', 'YYYY'));

INSERT INTO sample (sample_date) VALUES (TO_DATE('2005', 'YYYY'));

INSERT INTO sample (sample_date) VALUES (TO_DATE('2006', 'YYYY'));
```

If you then want to view the dates in DD-MM-YYYY format:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(sample_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS formatted_sample_date
  FROM sample;
```

Hope it helps...